# Find least positive three digit integer equal to sum of its digits plus twice the product of digits?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Find least positive three digit integer equal to sum of its digits plus twice the product of digits ?
My Attempt
let $a,b,c$ be three digits.According to given condition  $abc=a+b+c+2*a*b*c$. This leads to $9(11a+b)=2*a*b*c$ Thus one digit is divisible by 9 or two digits divisible by three.$(11a+b)$ is even implies digit $a$ and $b$ is of same parity. I am stuck here and can't proceed further. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good start.  Now I would say we need the digits large to make this work because you have $99a$ on the left and $2a\cdot b\cdot c$ on the right, so $b\cdot c \gt 49$.  As you want a factor $9$ and making $c$ large doesn't make $abc$ too much larger, I would try $c=9$.  That gives $11a+b=2a\cdot b, b=\frac {11a}{2a-1}$.  As $2a-1$ is coprime with $a$, it must divide into $11$, which gives $a=6, b=6$ for a candidate number of $669.$  All that is left is to prove there is none smaller.  Given $b \cdot c \gt 49$, and assuming $c \neq 9$ the only other choices are $(7,8), (8,7), (9,6), (9,7), (9,8)$.  The first two would force $a=9$ for the divisibility and that is larger than $669$ so we don't have to check them.

Comment: I have eventually reached this solution , after posting this problem , but then came the surprise. Answer is 397. So 669 is a solution , but not the least one.

Comment: The commonality of $b=9$ in the other cases makes it easy to check.  I had to go to bed last night.